# Direct access to nested classes and structures in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In my code the following pattern is recurrent:

```
class Assembler {/*...*/}; //does something, in this case assembles a matrix
class AssemblerParam {/*...*/}; //contains the parameters needed to create 
                                //an object of the Assembler class
class AssemblerReader {/*...*/}; //reads a file and creates an 
                                 //object of AssemblerParam
```

I have realized this can be organized a lot better by nesting AssemblerParam and AssemblerReader inside Assembler (plus some advantages for generic programming)

```
class Assembler {
public:
    class Param { /*...*/ };
    class Reader{ /*...*/ };
private:
    Param parameters;
};
```

However, now the implementation of the methods of Assembler is a lot less readable for things like this

```
void Assembler::method() {
    parameters.mesh.method(parameters.member.method());
    //the code now is cluttered with the word "parameters"
}
```

Instead I would like my code to read:

```
void Assembler::method() {
    mesh.method(member.method()); //a lot more readable
}
```

Any solution?

**Remark 1** 
Using inheritance like this

```
class AssemblerParam{/*...*/};
class Assembler : public AssemblerParam { /*...*/ };
```

would help on readability, but would pollute my namespace with classes SomethingParam.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally clicked submit before finishing writing the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

There can be no clean general solution to this problem; you must decide how to encapsulate things in a way that makes sense in the context of your project.

If `mesh` is used for things other than constructing the `Assembler`, it should probably be a member of `Assembler`. If constructing an `Assembler` requires so many parameters that the constructor is unreadable, then constructing the `AssemblerParam` would be just as difficult, so `AssemblerParam` doesn't solve that problem. There may be *subsets* of the parameter set that can be bundled into simple containers without complex methods, but that depends on the specifics of your case.

Comment: AssemblerReader builds AssemblerParam given a file name. I can also fill in the code AssemblerParam. It is to say, AssemblerParam unifies the way of creating an instance Assembler.

Comment: @DanielAlvesPaladim: Then why not have `AssemblerReader` build the `Assembler` directly? (I'm not sure what *"fill in the code AssemblerParam"* means.)